# object_list Django ListViews

Tags: django

```
class django.views.generic.list.ListView¶
A page representing a list of objects.

While this view is executing, self.object_list will contain the list of objects 
(usually, but not necessarily a queryset) that the view is operating upon.

Example views.py:

from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

from articles.models import Article

class ArticleListView(ListView):

    model = Article
    paginate_by = 100  # if pagination is desired

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context
```

What exactly is object_list? 
Is it inherited?
DO you have to define it? I wish the documentations would have clearly explanations rather than having to look through modules and modules and still not being able to find it, thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ListView`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/335c9c94acf263901fb023404408880245b0c4b4/django/views/generic/list.py#L194) inherits [`BaseListView`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/335c9c94acf263901fb023404408880245b0c4b4/django/views/generic/list.py#L139) in which you can see that

```
self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
```

If you go down further into [`MultipleObjectMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/335c9c94acf263901fb023404408880245b0c4b4/django/views/generic/list.py#L9) which is inherited by `BaseListView` you would see exactly how `get_queryset`  is implemented for ListView

---

Start with understanding [View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View) flow, methods and attributes and build up to understanding other views